# Javascript Returning NAN NAN NAN on IOS

Tags: javascript

I am using this function to convert UTC timestamp to Date according to the current user timezone

```js
let timeConversion = (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * -1 / 60) * 60 * 60;

function formatTime(time) {
  let d = new Date(((time + timeConversion) * 1000));
  return (d.getUTCDate() < 10 ? '0' + d.getUTCDate() : d.getUTCDate()) + '/' +
    (d.getUTCMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (d.getUTCMonth() + 1) : (d.getUTCMonth() + 1)) + '/' +
    d.getUTCFullYear().toString().substr(2, 4) + ' ' +
    (d.getUTCHours() < 10 ? '0' + d.getUTCHours() : d.getUTCHours()) + ':' +
    (d.getUTCMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + d.getUTCMinutes() : d.getUTCMinutes());
}

let allDates = document.getElementsByClassName("candidatedate");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(allDates, function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = formatTime(parseInt(el.innerHTML));
  el.className = "candidatedate";
});
```

```html
<span class="candidatedate">1604263179</span><span class="candidatedate">1604263177</span><span class="candidatedate">1604263176</span>
```

The code works perfectly on every platform except for IOS when I try to see the page it shows NAN NAN NAN NAN and the issue is that i can't debug the code on ios safari(I don't have usb cable for my IPHONE). Can someone help me with that ? Thanks

Comment: i just see a return sign, like u tried to code golf something but u turned into :l

Comment: what is an example of what u would want returned?

Comment: @TheBombSquad Yes bro I really tried but couldn't find any solution especially when I can't event debug that code on safari IOS, Tried user agent switcher, tried safari dev switch agent ...

Comment: yo put an example of what u want returned and i will put an answer

Comment: It would be helpful to debug the issue if you also displayed what kind of inputs you're feeding into the code. At the moment, the biggest suspect is `parseInt(el.innerHTML)`, where you'd get `NaN` if the input can't be parsed, but it's hard to say without further information.

Comment: <span class='candidatedate'>1604263179</span> Get the timestamp 1604263179 and convert it to users timezone 01/11/20 21:39 (GMT+1) 11/01/2020 8:39pm (UTC)

Comment: @Etheryte Please check i Updatet the question, let me know if any extra information is required. I really appreciate guys .

Comment: @The Bomb Squad, Etheryte The issue wasn't the javascript code it was ios chaging number to links I used <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> and the problem was solved. I wanted to thank you guys so much for supporting me :)

Comment: oh.. well just say innerText instead of innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to use [moment JS](https://momentjs.com/) to make this code readable using the `format` method.

Or write it at least more like that

```
function formatTime(time) {
   let d = new Date(((time + timeConversion) * 1000));
   return
      ('0' + d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)
      + '/' +
      ('0' + (d.getUTCMonth() + 1) ).slice(-2)
      + '/' +
      d.getUTCFullYear().toString().substr(2, 4)
      + ' ' + 
      ('0' + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2)
      + ':' +
      ('0' + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2)
      ;
};
```

So you got `NAN`. My guess is a problem with `time` variable.
It comes from `el.innerHTML`, a string converted with parseInt.

Could you try displaying it to verify the value?
Just with this small modification?

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(allDates, function(el) {
   const before = el.innerHTML;
   const after = formatTime(parseInt(el.innerHTML));
   el.innerHTML = `${before} // ${after}`;
   el.className = "candidatedate";
});
```

It everything is correct, you should maybe consider the fact that this code cannot run more than once... or it will fail with something like `parseInt('12/10/20 04:22)`.. So maybe adding a 'check no second run' could help.

Comment: you were right. In fact in desktop I get 1604263177 what's inside the div while in phone I get it as a link <a href="tel:1604263177"></a>. I don't know why !

Comment: Seems like a `Ho, the dev want to display a phone number, let's help him, we are a so smart phone` bad story :) Keep the faith.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from iOS trying to be very clever — and recognizing that your time strings could possibly be phone numbers.

The length matches the standard US phone number so iOS wraps them as links, allowing the user to click and call. `1604263177` becomes `<a href="tel:1604263177">1604263177</a>` and so forth. I suspect Android and other phones might display similar behavior.

The easiest solution is to switch from `innerHTML` over to `innexText`.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(allDates, function(el) {
  const input = parseInt(el.innerText, 10);
  el.innerHTML = input ? formatTime(input) : "";
  el.className = "candidatedate";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function formatTime(time){return(new Date(time-  (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60000)  ))}
//now basically 1 hr is 60000 units of the unit 'time' so that's my logic
//also new Date(randomTimeStamp) produces a new date off of that recorded timestamp
let d=formatTime(new Date().getTime())
console.log(d.toDateString()+" "+d.toLocaleTimeString()) //im not gonna copy a number when i can make one on the dot for illustration ;]
//also, d is what the actual value u want, i just logged something that seems like it
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

The issue was that safari auto converted number to links.

I solved this by using :

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```